# Spring - Tomcat error page instead of Whitelabel returned on requests to '..'

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, tomcat

If I make a request to `localhost:8080/..`, I am getting a Tomcat error page instead of the expected Whitelabel error page I have configured with Spring. 
My custom `ErrorController` is not logging anything on requests to `..`, suggesting that these errors aren't being handled by spring at all.

I've tested my error handling configuration by requesting at a URL that doesn't exist, such as `localhost:8080/not-defined`, and I get the expected Whitelabel error page.  Additionally, my `ErrorController` logs as expected.

We want to avoid exposing the details of our underlying web server.  Is there any way I can disable/override the Tomcat server error handling for this case?

Comment: I understand you are using spring-boot, right?
Are you deploying using a .jar or a .war file?
Are you using the embedded Tomcat provided by spring-boot or a separate Tomcat server?

Comment: We are deploying using a .jar, with the default embedded Tomcat provided by spring-boot

Comment: I couldn't reproduce this with a simple setup, I always get the response from my custom ErrorController, even with path "/..". Are there other configurations related to the web layer being done? What version of spring-boot are you using?

Comment: How are you making the request?  Many clients appear to normalize the path, so to reproduce you must ensure this is not happening (I tested with `curl --path-as-is localhost:8080/..`).  
I was able to reproduce with a fresh project generated from [Spring Initializer](https://start.spring.io/) at version 2.1.5, including only the Spring Web Starter

Comment: Oh! You are correct, it is reproducible only with `curl --path-as-is localhost:8080/..`, I didn't know about this normalization done by curl. This is interesting...
I am taking a deeper look at [spring-boot error handling](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-error-handling) and [spring MVC servlet configs](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-default-servlet-handler), to see if anything comes up. Maybe these links are helpful for your case :)

Comment: Thanks!  I will take a look and see if I can find anything